Tracking signal changes with effect() in web components made with Lit
I'm building an audio streaming web app, with the use of some web-components created with Lit and signals (through the library preact-signals) for global state management.
Here is how it works :
In a Track component, I update the signal when I click on a track.
// stw-track.ts
...
// onclick callback
launchTrack() {
  // update signal
  currentTrack.value = {
    title: this.title,
    artist: this.artist,
    duration: this.duration,
    coverUrl: this.coverUrl,
    manifest: this.manifest,
    playlist: this.playlist,
  }
}
...

Then in the player component, I listen the the currentTrack object changes, and I listen to the audio. I do that in the firstUpdated() lifecycle method because I need to access to an  element that is rendered in the shadow root.
// stw-player.ts
...
firstUpdated() {
  this.initShakaPlayer()

  effect(() => {
    // not called when signal change
    if (!this.remotePlayer) {
      return
    }
  
    this.listen(
      currentTrack.value.manifest!,
      currentTrack.value.playlist!,
      currentTrack.value,
      true
    ).catch((err: Error) => {
      this.player.unload()
      console.error(err)
    })
  })
}
...

However, the callback in effect() is not called when the track change. If I move the effect() function in the connectedCallback lifecycle methods, the callback is called but it cannot access to the  element that is rendered in the shadow-dom, since it has not been rendered yet.

I don't see why firstUpdated would behave differently than connectedCallback, but something you could try is turn connectedCallback async and await this.updateComplete from there before registering your effect.
